# Avocado growth seems stagnant after transfer to soil?

Tags: diagnosis, avocado

Avocado transferred to soil 3 weeks ago, had long full roots and was in water for about a year. Stem about 15cm long and leaves at the top. Once it stopped growing further I transferred it carefully to soil.

I heard the plant needs to grow its soil roots?
I clipped the stem at one of the points as the leaves ontop were dying after a week in the soil.

I made a little humidity dome and still nothing happening - pip green but top of stem going black :(
What so i do to save it?

Comment: Sounds like you left it in water for so long you used up all the reserves in the pit, so it's sitting in soil with a bunch of unsuitable roots, and it's exhausted its reserves.